# Disable log rotation for apache or move file location

Tags: apache-2.2, httpd, logging

I need to change the log retention for apache, currently is seems to be running on the default from logrotate.conf which is weekly. It creates 'access_log.1' 'access_log.2' and so on for each week. 
The problem is it deletes the last log file every week, 'access_log.5', I need the logs to keep going infinitely instead of the last log being deleted every week. 
It seems to be running on the default value from logrotate.conf - I don't want to change the default values held in that file, so I assume there is a way to change the retention using the /etc/logrotate.d/httpd file?

the contents are as follows:

```
/var/log/httpd/*log {
    missingok
    notifempty
    sharedscripts
    postrotate
        /sbin/service httpd reload > /dev/null 2>/dev/null || true
    endscript
}
```

what can I add/change to stop the last log being deleted every week?

Answer (score 3):

You would need to add the `rotate {value}` option to tell logrotate how many copies to keep.  The below will keep 52 copies.

```
/var/log/httpd/*log {
    missingok
    rotate 52
    notifempty
    sharedscripts
    postrotate
    /sbin/service httpd reload > /dev/null 2>/dev/null || true
    endscript
}
```

Comment: Is there a value to make it infinite? ie. '0'
or would I be better off setting it to 50 billion?

Comment: You could also use something like cronolog.  http://serverfault.com/questions/20337/cronolog-vs-logrotate http://serverfault.com/questions/41349/logrotate-rename-files-with-date

Answer (score 0):

It is surprisingly difficult to find an answer to this question. I ended up finding [this obscure 2003 forum post](https://www.linuxquestions.org/questions/linux-general-1/disable-log-rotation-in-site-76531/). The solution seems to be that you just disable the `cronjob` for `logrotate` at which by default is maybe at `/etc/cron.daily/logrotate`. This disables all rotation of logs everywhere on the machine, which is what I wanted. If you only want to do this for a specific application, I think you can maybe get away with creating an empty config file in `/etc/logrotate.d/apache2`. If you just delete this config file, I think it will default back to the global one at `/etc/logrotate.conf` and still rotate.